# Testing Add item to Array in Solidity and Ganache

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, solidity, web3js, ganache

I am experimenting with Solidty and facing a few issues while using arrays. Testing it on Remix is working fine. But, on my local code using Ganache 6.12.2 I can't make it work.

The test is just add a string to an array and then getting the array to make sure the data is there.

So, my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Program {

    address public funder;
    string[] public suppliers;
    string[] public buyers;
    uint public totalAmountProgram;
    uint public balance;
    uint public autoApproveLimit = 0;
    uint public fundingFee;

    bool public isActive;

    constructor(address _funder, uint _totalAmountProgram, uint _fundingFee) {
        funder = _funder;
        totalAmountProgram = _totalAmountProgram;
        balance = _totalAmountProgram;
        fundingFee = _fundingFee;
    }

    function activateProgram() public returns (bool) {
        isActive = true;
        return isActive;
    }

    function doSomethingToCheckBalanceAndDeactivateProgram() public {
        isActive = false;
    }

    function addSupplier(string memory _supplier) public {
        suppliers.push(_supplier);
    }

    function removeSupplier(string memory _supplier) public {
        for(uint i = 0; i < suppliers.length - 1; i++) {
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(suppliers[i])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_supplier))) {
                suppliers[i] = suppliers[suppliers.length - 1];
            }
        }

        suppliers.pop();
    }

    function getSuppliers() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return suppliers;
    }

    function addBuyer(string memory _buyer) public {
        buyers.push(_buyer);
    }

    function removeBuyer(string memory _buyer) public {
        for(uint i = 0; i < buyers.length - 1; i++) {
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(buyers[i])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_buyer))) {
                buyers[i] = buyers[buyers.length - 1];
            }
        }

        buyers.pop();
    }

    function getBuyers() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return buyers;
    }

    function updateAutoApprovalLimite(uint _autoApproveLimit) public returns (uint) {
        if (_autoApproveLimit < totalAmountProgram) {
            autoApproveLimit = _autoApproveLimit;
        }

        return autoApproveLimit;
    }

    function updateFundingFee(uint _fundingFee) public returns (uint) {
        fundingFee = _fundingFee;
        return fundingFee;
    }
}
```

My tests, the first 2 are passing

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { program } = require('../../scripts/compile');

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const accounts = {
    deployer: null,
    funders: [],
    buyers: [],
    suppliers: []
}

async function getAccounts() {
    const response = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    accounts.deployer = response.shift()
    accounts.funders = response.slice(0, 3);
    accounts.buyers = response.slice(3, 6);
    accounts.suppliers = response.slice(6);
}

const DEFAULT_MESSAGE = 'Hi there!';

let programContract;
beforeEach(async () => {
    // Get a list of all accounts
    await getAccounts()

    // Use first to deploy contract
    programContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(program.abi)
        .deploy({
            data: program.evm.bytecode.object,
            arguments: [accounts.funders[0], 10000000, 3],
        })
        .send({ from: accounts.deployer, gas: '5000000' });
});

describe('Program Contract', () => {
    it('deploy a contract', () => {
        assert.ok(programContract.options.address)
    })

    it('activate the program', async () => {
        const isActive = await programContract
            .methods
            .activateProgram()
            .call();

        // const isActive = await programContract
        //     .methods
        //     .isActive()
        //     .call();

        assert.equal(isActive, true)
    })

    it('add a supplier', async () => {
        const supplier = "Supplier 01";
        const tst = await programContract
            .methods
            .addSupplier(supplier)
            .call();
        const contractSuppliers = await programContract
            .methods
            .getSuppliers()
            .call();

        assert.equal(contractSuppliers.length, 1)

    })

})
```

But the third one is failing because I getting an empty array.

My dependencies:

```
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.1",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^9.1.2",
    "solc": "^0.8.9",
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
```

Test using Ganache and Solidity to add an String to an Array and recover it

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.call()` for `addSupplier`. Calls do not mutate the blockchain state. Use `.send()` instead.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

```
        const tst = await programContract
            .methods
            .addSupplier(supplier)
            .send();
```